# Control memory used by shelve

Tags: python, memory, shelve

I am using shelve in Python to handle a huge dictionary that would not fit in the memory, as well as to achieve persistence.

While running my code, which requires frequent retrieval and insertion into random locations in the dictionary, I noticed that the shelve is using only about 3% of the 4GB available memory. This is causing my code to run slower, as there would be greater number of read/writes from the disk required.

Is there any way to make the shelve use greater amount of available memory (say ~50%), so that number of hits in the memory are higher?

Comment: Yeah, possibly. I was thinking of MongoDB as it has JSON support. Better idea, is it?

Comment: Definitely. Why waste your time managing memory, when MongoDB (or some other) developers have already done that very efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ZODB or other key-value stores that integrate well with Python. Any object that can be shelved/pickled can go into ZODB. The shelve module doesnt seem to be designed for that kind of performance or consistency.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-zodb/

You can also go for an SQL solution, with the **pickle** module to serialize/unserialize that object to and from text. It is the heart of Shelve and ZODB. If you are feeling really adventurous, you can try an in-memory SQLite DB. SQLite is bundled in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I also highly recommend ZODB. You can port your shelve database to a ZODB database like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shelve
import ZODB, ZODB.FileStorage
import transaction
from optparse import OptionParser
import os
import sys
import re

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

parser = OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-o", "--output", dest = "out_file", default = False, help ="original shelve database filename")
parser.add_option("-i", "--input", dest = "in_file", default = False, help ="new zodb database filename")

parser.set_defaults()
options, args = parser.parse_args()

if options.in_file == False or options.out_file == False :
    print "Need input and output database filenames"
    exit(1)

db = shelve.open(options.in_file, writeback=True)
zstorage = ZODB.FileStorage.FileStorage(options.out_file)
zdb = ZODB.DB(zstorage)
zconnection = zdb.open()
newdb = zconnection.root()

for key, value in db.iteritems() :
    print "Copying key: " + str(key)
    newdb[key] = value

transaction.commit()
```